Is there a way to calculate the limit of this Series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right)$?
I am working on a kind of Quantum-Monte-Carlo-code and currently try to evaluate some of the terms analytically to find a set of Monte-Carlo states with a less severe sign problem (blocking).
While doing so I came across some series of the form:
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right)$$
An example for a special case would be:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{e^{-\beta x}}{(x-D)^n}\right)
$$
Has someone an idea of how to write that sum in a closed form?
What I tried is find a $g$ and an $y$ so that:
$$
    \frac{d^n}{dy^n}  g(y) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right)
$$
for all n, which would turn the series into a taylor series. But it appears, that I produced a contradiction between fulfilling the $n = 0 $ and the $n = 1$ case and fulfilling the $n = 2$ case, so that simple approach seems not to work.
Edit: Following Pedros comment I tryed expanding $f(x)$ as a taylor series:
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{\sum_{k = 0}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!}\left. \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) \right|_{x = 0} x^k}{x^n}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n! k!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\left. \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) \right|_{x = 0} x^{k-n}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n! k!} \left(\left. \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) \right|_{x = 0} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} x^{k-n}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 2n}^\infty \frac{1}{n! k!} \left(\left. \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) \right|_{x = 0} \frac{(k-n)!}{(k-2n)!} x^{k-2n}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n! (l + 2n)!} \left(\left. \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left(\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} f(x) \right)\right|_{x = 0} \frac{(l+n)!}{l!} x^{l}\right)
=$$
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \frac{(l+n)!}{(l + 2n)!} \left(\left. \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left(\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} f(x) \right)\right|_{x = 0} \frac{x^{l}}{l!} \right)
$$
,which structurally looks again similar to a Taylor-series, but not so much so, that I would know what to do with it.

I'm pretty sure (for the general case) this strongly depends on the form of $f$.

As @NDewolf, this strongly depends on your choice of $f$. You can expand the $n$th derivative using the general product rule, (see here) but after that, there's not much you can do (I believe it becomes some sort of generating function, I could be wrong though)

Did you try expanding $f$ in Taylor series?

@Pedro I editet the question.
